# For each date, how to calculate days until/since (aka lead/lag) the closest pay period?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a range of `date`s as below. Two of these dates are `payDay`. For each date that is 3 days before and after a payday, I want to return the number of days leading up to and after `payDay`.

Below, `whatIHave` illustrates my data and `whatIWant` shows the outcome. I'd like to do this in `dplyr`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```r
whatIHave <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date("2019/11/01"), as.Date("2019/12/01"), "days"),
  payDay = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

```r
whatIWant <- data.frame(
  date = seq(as.Date("2019/11/01"), as.Date("2019/12/01"), "days"),
  payDay = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  payDayLag = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to identify the rows where 'payDay' is 1

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
ind <- which(whatIHave$payDay == 1)
```

Create a sequence of row index based on the 'ind'

```
v1 <- unlist(lapply(ind, function(i) (i-3):(i+3)))
```

Then, using a grouping variable based on the logical vector created by checking 'v1' `%in%` the sequence of rows (`row_number()`), create the 'payDayLag' by subtracting the `row_number()` from the row index where the 'payDay' is 1

```
whatIHave %>% 
  group_by(group =  rleid(row_number() %in% v1)) %>% 
  mutate(payDayLag = if(all(payDay == 0)) 0 
         else row_number() - row_number()[payDay==1])  %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-group)
# A tibble: 31 x 3
#   date       payDay payDayLag
#   <date>      <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 2019-11-01      0         0
# 2 2019-11-02      0         0
# 3 2019-11-03      0         0
# 4 2019-11-04      0         0
# 5 2019-11-05      0         0
# 6 2019-11-06      0         0
# 7 2019-11-07      0         0
# 8 2019-11-08      0         0
# 9 2019-11-09      0         0
#10 2019-11-10      0        -3
# … with 21 more rows
```

---

If we want this in a single chain

```
library(tidyverse)
whatIHave %>%
    mutate(ind = row_number() * payDay) %>% 
    filter(payDay == 1) %>% 
    mutate(ind = map(ind, ~ (.x-3):(.x+3))) %>% 
    group_by(grp = row_number()) %>%
    unnest %>% 
    mutate(payDayLag =  row_number() - row_number()[4]) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-payDay, -grp, -date) %>% 
    right_join(whatIHave %>%
                   mutate(ind = row_number()))  %>%
    mutate(payDayLag = replace_na(payDayLag, 0))
```

---

Or without a join

```
whatIHave %>%
   mutate(ind =  list(map(which(payDay == 1), ~  (.x -3):(.x + 3)))) %>%
   group_by(grp = rleid(row_number() %in% unlist(ind[[1]]) )) %>%
   select(-ind) %>% 
   mutate(payDayLag = if(all(payDay == 0)) 0 
         else row_number() - row_number()[payDay == 1]) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun - I appreciate the time and thinking here.